# How to assign values to different IBActions in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

In my app i want to load my cells based on IBActions.here is my two IBActions,

```
-(IBAction)action1:(id)sender
{
}

-(IBAction)action2:(id)sender
{
}
```

I want to load like this

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (value == 0)
{
    return 96;
}
else if(value == 1)
{
    return 237;
}
return 0;
}
```

How can i assign my value=0 to my action1 and value =1 to my action2?

Comment: Actually What you want ?

Comment: @IOSDeveloper. How can i assign my value=0 to my action1 and value =1 to my action2?

Comment: @User558 You have everything... Just do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 -(IBAction)action1:(id)sender
  {
    self.value  = 0
    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Write below code

```
-(IBAction)action1:(id)sender
{ self.value = 0
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}

-(IBAction)action2:(id)sender
{
  self.value = 1
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create two method you can use tag property of UIButton class

```
-(IBAction)action1:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (sender.tag == 0)
    {
        self.value = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        self.value = 1;
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```